Deriving a calculation for re-orders by date and customer name
I am trying to derive a calculation for re-orders by date and customer name. With the output being in "weeks". And if its easy to switch between "days" and "months" as well.
For example. " Marriot overall had xx weeks on average between orders, and Marriot Los Angeles had xx weeks on average between orders".
Also would need to be able to calculate "Last order from today". So for example if a customers last order was "Jan 1st 2023" and they never ordered again, I would like to calculate the time between than and today (current_timestamp)
Essentially a Datediff, but had trouble getting it to work while factoring in the customer name and customer name sub.



Order Date
Customer Name
Customer_Name_Sub




5/20/2022
Marriot
Los Angeles


5/20/2022
Marriot
New York


5/26/2022
Marriot
Los Angeles


5/27/2022
Marriot
Miami


6/10/2022
Marriot
Los Angeles


6/16/2022
Marriot
Miami


6/22/2022
Marriot
Los Angeles


6/29/2022
Marriot
Miami


7/6/2022
Marriot
Los Angeles


7/8/2022
Marriot
Miami


7/13/2022
Marriot
Miami


7/20/2022
Marriot
Miami


7/28/2022
Marriot
Miami


8/3/2022
Marriot
Los Angeles


8/30/2022
Marriot
Los Angeles


9/14/2022
Marriot
Los Angeles


10/18/2022
Marriot
Los Angeles


12/22/2022
Marriot
Los Angeles


1/9/2023
Marriot
Los Angeles




This is best done in tableau prep with a lookup function

What would be the approach in Tableau prep, I'm not too familiar with it but have it

I’d start with some simple practice tasks to first Tableau Prep, then when you’re comfortable with Tableau Prep, read about Lookup() in the Tableau Help https://help.tableau.com/current/prep/en-us/prep_multirow_calculations.htm

Method used is Dense_Rank function and PARTITION with Lookup:
Dense_Rank:

This gives a ranked number for each order date by the customer value to know what orders came first and last
{PARTITION [Customer Name]: { ORDERBY [Order Date] ASC: RANK_DENSE()}}


^ Column labeled as Order_Rank_Customer
Partition/Lookup:

This uses the Dense_Rank as a reference to know which dates by customer were first/last. This brings back the previous order of the specific customer  to generate a column I labeled "Previous Order Date"
{ PARTITION [Customer Name]:
{ ORDERBY [Order_Rank_Customer] DESC: LOOKUP([Order Date],1)}}


Days Since Last Order:

This is a simple DATEDIFF with a ABS (Absolute value) since it generates a negative number
ABS(DATEDIFF('day',[Order Date],[Last Re-Order Date Customer]))



Using a table calc for calculations that depend on row order  works, but doesn’t scale up well for large data sets, because it has to fetch so much data to perform the table calc client-side. Doing similar calcs up front, such as with Tableau Prep or a sql windowing query will perform better for large data

These are all done in Tableau Prep
